# jQuery selector equivalent to ~ but reverse

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This does not seem to be in the docs of jQuery API, so it probably does not exist, but just wanted to get confirmation from fellow experts.

Is there an equivalent to `$('prev ~ next')` but for previous siblings? (No methods, just selectors)

Comment: So in the selector example you gave, you would be selecting the `prev` element. Right?

Comment: that's right, patrick. I'm just curious to see if there is a selecting way to do that. Is the "~" symbol coming from xPath btw? I'll try their docs just to see if anything there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about negating the selector?

```
$('parent > *:not(prev ~ next)')
```

[Working example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/oqogo4)

Comment: thanks casablanca, that is I think the best way to do it without getting very messy in the selector!

Comment: I have to say, I think it ridiculous to use a selector like this instead of the `prev` function.  Seriously, what are you gaining?  If you knew how jQuery handles this selector beneath the surface you would not use it.

Comment: @Josh: Totally agree with you. It's going to be terribly inefficient, but I don't know why the OP wants it this way.

Comment: just out of curiosity actually. wondering why there was a selector for next and not one for prev. playing around with a language is also a good way to learn about it ;)

Comment: I am half-tempted to run benchmarks on your JSBin example vs. `$("#parent > #a4").prevAll("div").css('color', 'red');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`